# unable to update packages /dependencies

Tags: updates, kernel

I am getting this long update error:

```
the following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-modules-nvidia-510-5.15.0-58-generic:
depends:nvidia-kernel-common-510[<=
510.108.03-1] but525.125.06-0ubuntu0.20.04-1
is to be installed
linux-modules-nvidia-510.15.0-57-generic:
depends:nvidia510-5.15.0-57-generic:
depends:nvidia-kernel-common-510[<=
510.108.03-1] but 525.125.0-56-generic:
depends:nvidia-kernel-common-510[<=
510.108.03-1] but 52.125,06-0ubuntu0,20,04.1
is to be installed
linux-modules-nvidia510-5.15.0-60-generic:
depends:nvidiaa-kernel-common-510[<=
510.108.03-1] but 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.20,04,1
is to be installed.
```

All help is appreciated.